# Issue On Getting Uploaded Image Name With Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the uploaded image name like this

```js
    $(function() {
    $("input[name=file]").on("change", function() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
      var fimeName = $(this).val(files[0].name);
        console.log(fimeName);
       }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

but it is not working and I am getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: files is not defined

Can you please let me know what I am doing wring? Thansk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the files from the event within the click function.

```js
    $(function() {
    $("input[name=file]").on("change", function() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        //what are you trying to do here?    
        var fileName = this.files[0].name;
        console.log(fileName);
       }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

Comment: Thanks AnotherDev but how Can I store the name in var?

Comment: I mean I do not want only print it out in console! what I need is storing the file name in `var fileName;`

Comment: and can you please let me know what is the role of `e.target.files;` here?

Comment: You don't actually need that, you can just use `this.files`. e.target.files was getting the input field from the event and then finding the files.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `this`:

```
var fimeName = $(this).val(this.files[0].name);
```

But regardless, couple things: You can't explicitly set a value with `val()` on an input type of file (except for the empty string), and `fimeName` here is going to be assigned the jQuery matched set of `this`, not any string value.